# Typescript and Tensorflow.js models

Tags: tensorflow.js

In the Blazeface [1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/blazeface) source file `face.ts` there is a class `BlazeFaceModel` with the constructor `model: tfconv.GraphModel`. I need to call this model from my `index.ts` file. In the official Blazeface demo `index.js` this is done by `let model;`.

For the sake of writing strict Typescript, how should I declare the type of `model` in my Typescript file? I could import

```
import * as tfconv from '@tensorflow/tfjs-converter';
```

and set `const model: tfconv.Graphmodel`, but how "valid" is that approach?

Comment: Do you have an error ? If yes maybe consider adding it to your question otherwise it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: No error, more like a quest for "best practice" or principals when combining Typescript and Tensorflow.js. I am not sure how to rephrase the question, sorry.